# How to remove url starting with www.*** from a string using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I am trying to filter out all URL from a string input. Currently, I have a regex that is able to find URLs starting with `http://` or `https://` or `ftp://` as seen below:

```js
var _input = document.querySelector("#input");
var btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
var results = document.querySelector("#results");

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
var input_ = _input.value;
var cleanInput = input_.replace(/(?:https?|ftp):\/\/[\n\S]+/g, '');
results.innerHTML = cleanInput;
});
```

```html
<textarea id="input" rows="5" style="width: 200px;"></textarea>
<button id="btn">SUBMIT</button>
<div id="results"></div>
```

What Regex should I use to match `www.***` and also it should not case sensitive. http or HTTP should also be match.

Comment: Try `.replace(/(?:(?:http|ftp)s?:\/\/|www\.)[\n\S]+/ig, '');`

Comment: Have you tried to create the regex that you are looking for yourself? If not, you should do that; if so, could you share what you've tried in your question? It helps to show you've put effort into figuring out the problem yourself, and gives answerers a starting point to really help your understanding, rather than to just give you a regular expression that works.

Comment: This works like magic, thanks @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: @Florrie I included the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may adjust your regex to

```
.replace(/(?:(?:http|ftp)s?:\/\/|www\.)[\n\S]+/ig, '');
```

**Details**

- `ig` - ignore case (`i`) and global (`g`) modifiers to match all occurrences in a case insensitive way
- `(?:(?:http|ftp)s?:\/\/|www\.)` - `https://`, `http://`, `ftp://`, `ftps://` or `www.`
- `[\n\S]+` - 1 or more non-whitespace or LF chars

Comment: Nice solution. Interesting that you did respect non-whitespace and LF chars. Thumbs up for that

Comment: @r3dst0rm It is just the same as OP regex, I only added required fixes.